# Creating and configuring .bash_profile

Tags: bash, anaconda

I was setting path for anaconda. an answer to a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675907/how-to-run-conda) has the following solution. I searched for `.bash_profile`, but I can't seem to find it. How do I setup this file and get it to run on startup?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ubuntu does not normally have a `.bash_profile`

You should add your change to the end of  `.profile` instead, since this file will not be read if `.bash_profile` exists, and Ubuntu normally has code in `.profile` to at least source `.bashrc` in login shells, so we want it to be read!

I recommend you don't create any new files, but modify the existing `.profile` (found in your home directory, but hidden as it starts with a `.`) instead to add to your PATH. This is an appropriate and usual way of modifying your environment in Ubuntu