# Cannot update bash_profile in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: command-line, bash

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 in VMware on a Windows 10 host. I am trying to install Laravel, I have actually installed Laravel successfully but I want to set the laravel command globally, and in order to do so I tried updating the bash_profile by opening it in nano and then I wrote :

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

and then saved it. Now when I try to see if the `$PATH` was successfully updated by typing echo $PATH, it doesn't show me the newly added `~/.composer/vendor/bin` path. But when I again open the bash_profile in nano, I can see my `export path` line in it I recently added. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You'd have to log out and back in or `source` the file, but you should append that line to `.profile` instead, since creating `.bash_profile` will cause `.profile` not to be read, and `.profile` contains commands by default in Ubuntu.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/824829/creating-and-configuring-bash-profile/824848#824848

Comment: Thanks a lot , it worked, if you'd answered I would have accepted it. Thanks anyways.

Comment: It's a pleasure to help :) I'd rather not duplicate content if possible, keeps the site tidy :)